# Vue router is not loading the component registered to the children path: ""

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

So, I have this weird behaviour from the Vue Router.

AllNotesPage.vue

```
<template>
  <h1>testing</h1>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

NotesHome.vue

```
<template>
  <h1 class="text-center">Notes</h1>
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'create-note' }">
    <v-btn>Add note<v-icon end icon="mdi-plus-thick"></v-icon></v-btn>
  </router-link>

  <div v-if="notes.length > 0">
    <p>NoTeS eXiSt</p>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <h3 class="text-center">No NoTeS yEt</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
/****************************************************
 ** IMPORTS
 ****************************************************/

// store imports.
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

/****************************************************
 ** CONFIGURATION
 ****************************************************/

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("notesModule", {
      notes: "getAllNotes",
    }),
  },
};
</script>
```

router.js

```
const routes = [
  { name: "welcome", path: "/", component: WelcomePage },
  { name: "about", path: "/about", component: AboutPage },
  {
    name: "notes",
    path: "/notes",
    component: AllNotesPage,
    children: [
      { name: "notes-home", path: "", component: NotesHome },
      { name: "create-note", path: "create-note", component: CreateNote },
    ],
  },
];
```

NavigationDrawer.vue

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer permanent>
    <v-list nav density="compact">
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'notes' }" v-slot="{ isActive }">
        <v-list-item
          prepend-icon="mdi-view-dashboard"
          value="notes"
          title="Notes"
          :class="isActive ? 'v-list-item--active' : ''"
        >
        </v-list-item>
      </router-link>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'about' }" v-slot="{ isActive }">
        <v-list-item
          prepend-icon="mdi-forum"
          value="about"
          title="About"
          :class="isActive ? 'v-list-item--active' : ''"
        >
        </v-list-item>
      </router-link>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
```

Okay, so what is actually happening. I have a navbar from which I navigate to an about page (which works perfectly) or a notes page. When loading the notes page, and the path is “/notes”, I expect to see the NotesHome.vue component. It appears only if I reload the page while on this path or I manually type in the URL, but otherwise, there is nothing.

I found a way for this to work. It works if I change the way I navigate from the nav bar. So, instead of :to="{ name: ‘notes’ }" I write :to="{ path: ‘/notes’ }" and it works.

I want to understand what causes this weird behaviour.

Thank you for being patient and reading all of that. Also, sorry for the not so coherent writing

Comment: try to navigate to { name: 'notes-home' }

Comment: That also works, but I was wondering why this is happening